# Cannot download my app on iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, adhoc

I see "Impossible to download..." error on my iPhone with iOS 5 when I try to download my application signed with AdHoc certificate. 
I can install this app on the same phone via iTunes.
It worked fine on the same phone before the last update to iOS 5. It still works fine for many beta-testers that have not updated their phones to iOS 5.
I can install  this application on my iPhone running iOS 5

Is there something special in the Entitlements file now? Something special on the server side?
How to fix this problem with the ipa downloading?

Comment: Check to see if you have any expired profiles on the device (Settings / General / Profiles). Sometimes they interfere with adhoc app installation.

Comment: maybe regenerating the certificates and provisioning profiles might fix it....

Comment: I've deleted already all certificates from the phone. It didn't help.

Comment: I will regenerate the provisioning profile - seems like only that left

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the manifest file - this file should contain correct links to the app, to the app icon, the correct version number. In this case the problem was in the version number - at least, I remember it so.